# Draw and Map a texture to system RAM using opengl

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I want to use OpenGL ES 2.0 on my Raspberry Pi to draw a rectangle whose RGB pixel values will be stored in a buffer in memory later for further processing via CPU.

In other words, this is the path:  RGB buffer in RAM -> texture on GPU -> draw -> back to RAM. Eventually, the kind of thing I want to do should be clear by reading the following simple program.

I have tried to do this by essentially creating an `EGLImage` context via `eglCreateImageKHR()`, but the program fails with error `0x501` (from an assertion from the `GLCHK` macro):

```
#include <bcm_host.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <system_error>
#include <memory>

/* Uncomment to enable extra GL error checking */
#define CHECK_GL_ERRORS
#if defined(CHECK_GL_ERRORS)
#define GLCHK(X) \
do { \
    GLenum err = GL_NO_ERROR; \
    X; \
   while ((err = glGetError())) \
   { \
      std::cout << "GL error " << err << " in file " << __FILE__<< ", line " << __LINE__ << ' '; \
      assert(err == GL_NO_ERROR); \
      exit(err); \
   } \
} \
while(0)
#else
#define GLCHK(X) X
#endif /* CHECK_GL_ERRORS */

void demo() {
    EGLDisplay eglDisplay = 0;
    EGLConfig eglConfigWindow = 0;
    EGLSurface eglSurfacePbuffer = 0;
    EGLContext eglContext = 0;

    const EGLint attribListWindow[] = {
                                       EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
                                       EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                                       EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                                       EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                                       EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                                       EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                                       EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                                       EGL_NONE                                       
    };
    const EGLint srfPbufferAttr[] = {
                                     EGL_WIDTH, 640,
                                     EGL_HEIGHT, 480,
                                     EGL_NONE
    };

   const EGLint context_attribs[] = {
      EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 1,
      EGL_NONE
   };

    EGLint iMajorVersion, iMinorVersion;
    int iConfigs;

    eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (eglDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
        throw std::runtime_error {"error eglGetDisaply()"};

    auto result = eglInitialize(eglDisplay, &iMajorVersion, &iMinorVersion);
    if (result == EGL_FALSE)
        throw std::runtime_error {"error eglInitialize()"};

    //result = eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribListPbuffer, &eglConfigWindow, 1, &iConfigs);
    result = eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribListWindow, &eglConfigWindow, 1, &iConfigs);
    if (result == EGL_FALSE)
        throw std::system_error(result, std::generic_category(), "Error setting configuration for the given display: check your settings");

    auto context = eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfigWindow, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, context_attribs);
    if (context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
        throw std::runtime_error{"error eglCreateContext()"};                

    eglSurfacePbuffer = eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfigWindow, srfPbufferAttr);
    if (eglSurfacePbuffer == EGL_NO_SURFACE)
        throw std::runtime_error{"error CreatePbufferSurface(). " + std::to_string(eglGetError())};                

    eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurfacePbuffer, eglSurfacePbuffer, eglContext);

    GLuint texture;                          // Name for the preview texture
    EGLImageKHR egl_image = EGL_NO_IMAGE_KHR; // The current preview EGL image

    glClearColor(0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0); // random color
    glClearDepthf(1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const int bytes_per_pixel = 4;
    unsigned char buffer[640 * 480 * bytes_per_pixel] = {}; // 0x77 to see if it will be changed somehow

    GLCHK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture));
    egl_image = eglCreateImageKHR(eglDisplay, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_IMAGE_BRCM_MULTIMEDIA, (EGLClientBuffer) buffer, NULL);
    GLCHK(glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, &egl_image));

    glReadPixels(0, 0, 640, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
        throw std::runtime_error{"error glReadPixels():" + std::to_string(eglGetError())};

    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurfacePbuffer);

    // print the buffer pixel values, should be different from 0x00
    for (auto x : buffer)
        std::cout << std::hex << int(x) << ' ';

   // Terminate

   /* Delete OES textures */
   glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
   eglDestroyImageKHR(eglDisplay, egl_image);
   egl_image = EGL_NO_IMAGE_KHR;
    
   /* Terminate EGL */
   eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
   eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, context);
   eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurfacePbuffer);
   eglTerminate(eglDisplay);
}

int main() {
    atexit(bcm_host_deinit);
    bcm_host_init();
    demo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems in your code. You're requesting an ES 1.0 context, while everything else in your code, and your question, suggests that you're planning to use ES 2.0:

```
const EGLint context_attribs[] = {
   EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 1,
   EGL_NONE
};
```

You need client version 2 for ES 2.0.

The most direct problem is that you're using the `texture` variable uninitialized:

```
GLuint texture;                          // Name for the preview texture
...
GLCHK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture));
```

`texture` is not set between these two statements. You need a `glGenTextures(1, &texture)` to create a valid texture id.